# Is the basis of a product topology also the basis of a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

consider the topological spaces $(\Omega_{i},\tau_{i}),i \in \mathbb N$

We know that  $D:=\{\times_{i\in \mathbb N} A_{i}: A_{i}\in\tau_{i} ,A_{i}=\Omega_{i}$ for all but finitely many $i\}$ is basis of the product topology $\tau$

Is it always true that this $D$ is a basis of the product $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(\tau)$?

Comment: It should be all but *finitely many* $i$ as the basis of the product topology. Your $D$ is part of the sigma algebra $\sigma(\tau)$ though, and form a superset of the basis, in general.

Comment: Maybe we need the product to be perfectly normal (e.g. metrisable) as well. Not sure yet.

Comment: what do you mean by "*the* product $\sigma$-algebra" ? Any family you take will generate *some* $\sigma$-algebra

Comment: Considering the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra this should be true, if all spaces 2nd countable.

Comment: Note that for general spaces the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the product topology (the product Borel $\sigma$-algebra) need not be the same as the product $\sigma$-algebra of the Borel $\sigma$-algebras of the factor spaces. Are you aware of that? Which of the two $\sigma$-algebras do you mean on the product?